# How to add user to R Server ? How can I change the username and password of current RServer

Tags: r, shiny, r-server

We have Deployed R Server in AWS. We name given user name and password through shell command while installing. How can I change the existing username and password?

I am not able to find a way to add a user. Please help me.

Comment: If you have developed it you are probably the only person who can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question but what I understood is you wanna change username and password of rserver . If so than you can change it from shell again and from terminal .following link will guide you clearly
https://statistics.byu.edu/how-to-change-rstudio-passwordc